# Gettin the values by Hashmap and display them in a custom list view

Tags: android, listview, hashmap

I am designing an app in which i am using custom adapter and in that i am putting the value using hash map,

```
HashMap<String,String> temp = new HashMap<String,String>();
            temp.put(KEY_MODE, Mode);
            temp.put(KEY_PHONEMODE, PhoneMode);
            settingsList.add(temp);
```

I want to display my text like this,
**Mode**: RINGING MODE
Mode in Bold but ringing mode is in normal text.
I could get the desired text.
I am putting both the values using different hashkeys and different text view but I getting the text like.
:Ringing Mode Mode

Here is some code which,I am using,

```
static final String KEY_PHONEMODE = "PHONEMODE";
        static final String KEY_MODE = "MODE";
```

after this,
in on click listener,

```
Mode ="Phone Mode";
HashMap<String,String> temp = new HashMap<String,String>();
            temp.put(KEY_MODE, Mode);
            temp.put(KEY_PHONEMODE, PhoneMode);
            settingsList.add(temp);
```

I have used margin allignment but getting same problem.

Comment: are u want text in listview or in oher wdget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your text using [`Html.fromHtml(<HTML Formatted Code String>)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29).

So for example, `Html.fromHtml("<b>Mode</b>" + valueFromMap);`, in turn will return a `Spanned`-object, which in turn you can directly set into your `TextView` in your custom `ListView`.

Another option would be creating a custom row layout and having 2 different `TextView`s for each formatting.